# JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [org.postgresql]

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jboss

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([    
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),     
    ("jdbc-driver" => "PostgresJDBCDriver") 
]) - failure description: "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [org.postgresql]"
```

I am getting above error while running my server. I am using JBoss server.

Comment: Do you have a module defined for the PostgreSQL driver?

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer right here on StackOverflow: [How to add PostgreSQL datasource to WildFly 9.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222860/how-to-add-postgresql-datasource-to-wildfly-9-0)

After reading from the above link I realized that I was missing the postgres directory.
So then I created the directory: `/postgres/main/` in here : `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/postgres/main/` and created the `module.xml` file.
Then copy and paste the postgres driver to the same directory. Restart JBoss and it should work properly.

Comment: Also be careful with names `postgres != postgresql`.