# WildFly ClassNotFoundException Hibernate, load built-in Hibernate library in WildFly 14 without manifest file?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I have set up a Java web application that uses JPA. My container is WildFly 14. I'm using Maven.

If I deploy my WAR without manifest file containing dependency for `org.hibernate`, the container displays ClassNotFoundException for Hibernate-related classes.

My question, is this the normal behavior of WildFly deployment? I'm aiming for portable war file, so what would happen if I bring the same war to another Java EE container whose JPA implementation isn't hibernate?

---

`persistence.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">

    <persistence-unit name="jpa-example">
        <jta-data-source>java:/PostgresDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>id.ferdi.training.entity.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
<!--            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/training" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="training" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="training" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />-->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>id.ferdi.training</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebPortal</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>WebPortal Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>WebPortal</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
<!--          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifestEntries>
                <Dependencies>org.hibernate</Dependencies>
              </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
          </configuration>-->
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

add full error log

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: jpa-example] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1016)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:942)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.api@2.2//javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.api@2.2//javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at deployment.WebPortal2.war//id.ferdi.training.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.api@1.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
    at javax.servlet.api@1.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:551)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at net.bytebuddy//net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:139)
    at net.bytebuddy//net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:344)
    at net.bytebuddy//net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:159)
    at net.bytebuddy//net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:353)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.load(ByteBuddyState.java:181)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.loadProxy(ByteBuddyState.java:107)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyHelper.buildProxy(ByteBuddyProxyHelper.java:54)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyFactory.postInstantiate(ByteBuddyProxyFactory.java:62)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error invoking java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup#defineClass
    at net.bytebuddy//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingLookup$Dispatcher$ForJava9CapableVm.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:1486)
    at net.bytebuddy//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingLookup.inject(ClassInjector.java:1250)
    at net.bytebuddy//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$UsingLookup.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:419)
    at net.bytebuddy//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:79)
    at net.bytebuddy//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4247)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.lambda$load$0(ByteBuddyState.java:185)
    at net.bytebuddy//net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:137)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.System$2.defineClass(System.java:2131)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:964)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at net.bytebuddy//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingLookup$Dispatcher$ForJava9CapableVm.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:1482)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy from [Module "deployment.WebPortal2.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 90 more
```

---

postgresql setup in WildFly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTIU9.png)

Also tested against built-in ExampleDS, still the same.

---

[WAR sample in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pymB588suRC5dUYQeiG0jyXDKm3_EUxU/view?usp=sharing)

---

A bit of information gathering:

I think WildFly here indeed load the Java EE 8 API and its underlying implementation automatically. But, for others, we should activate it explicitly, using manifest file or `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. Ref [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7).

However, [`org.hibernate` should automatically be loaded](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployment).

Comment: Probably have a pom.xml that is hibernate specific or something. You should be using the Java EE API specification, there should be no general reason to have org.hibernate in the manifest. I know if you can make a purely generic .war EE application but maybe to some extent.

Comment: Do you use a persistence.xml?

Comment: @wirnse add `persistence.xml`

Comment: @K.Nicholas I added `pom.xml` for the project.

I'm still getting this:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy from [Module "deployment.WebPortal.war" from Service Module Loader]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your [WAR](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pymB588suRC5dUYQeiG0jyXDKm3_EUxU/view?usp=sharing) and noticed that the location of your persistence.xml is `META-INF/persistence.xml` this should be `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml`

Have a look at [Wildfly Quickstart Hibernate](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/14.x/hibernate).

For further reading:

[Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro003.htm)

[Wildfly JPA Reference Guide](http://docs.wildfly.org/14/Developer_Guide.html#JPA_Reference_Guide):

> During application deployment, JPA use is detected (e.g. persistence.xml or @PersistenceContext/Unit annotations) and injects Hibernate dependencies into the application deployment.

Comment: I don't know why I chose that location for my `persistence.xml`. Now it loads okay, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, you should just be using the Java EE API dependency in your pom. Wildfly seems to come with a built in ExampleDS but I don't think that's portable, but you can update the persistence.xml to suit your needs. This gets me started:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>minimaljavaee</groupId>
    <artifactId>minimaljavaee</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

EDIT: Persistence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:standalone" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Hi, i've adopted your pom.xml, but the issue still  persists. This is my testing WAR [in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pymB588suRC5dUYQeiG0jyXDKm3_EUxU/view?usp=sharing), but it will need a `java:/PostgresDS` in `persistence.xml`. Could you maybe inspect this file if there's something wrong with the way I package stuff?

Comment: Did you add a postgres module to wildfly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222860/how-to-add-postgresql-datasource-to-wildfly-9-0

Comment: I added it as a deployment jar. After that, I set up data source from admin console.

Comment: well I don't know what that means. I worked with Wildfly.11. You'll need to step back and start with the basics and add in things until you know what's going on. I added persistence.xml for the ExampleDS using hsqldb.

Comment: That's the recommended way to deploy database in WildFly 14 (that I've read). I've switched to the ExampleDS and the error still persists.